# pick free ports randomly

Tags: python, sockets, port

I've followed a tutorial step by step about python sockets, and at first it worked. I had a server.py and a client.py file. But sometimes I got random errors like :

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

so I changed my port from 9999 (recommanded in the tutorial) to a number above 90000 and pushed my commit (I work with github)
When I ran it again, I knew it was wrong so I set it back to normal. But since then, whatever port I enter, it rejects it with :

```
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

I saw a solution on stackoverflaw : the pc itself picks free ports randomly (so that it never gets refused), here is what I found :

```
sock.bind(('', 0)).
```

The thing is, in my code, I have an Ip adress (lets say '127.0.0.1', I changed it from my orignial) in the server.py file, and the same in my client.py file. With the code from above, I don't know how to apply that, because if I write these appostrophy instead of the ip address '127.0.0.1', in my client.py, it won't work right?

here is my code if you need it :

```
# server.py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # l'addresse IP de mon ordinateur (dans ce cas-ci, c'est mon PC fixe)
PORT = 9999  # port utilisé pour communiquer

# création du serveur, indiquation des normes de réseau (TCP)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))  # donne une adresse au serveur

server.listen(5)  # crée une connection (le chiffre 5 signifie : 5 connections en attente maximum)

while True:
    communication_socket, address = server.accept()  # accepte toutes les connections envoyées au serveur
    print(f"Connecté à {address}")
    message = communication_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')  # décode le message envoyé par le client
    print(f"Le message du client est : {message}")
    communication_socket.send(f"Merci pour votre message !".encode('utf-8'))  # encoder un nouveau message
    communication_socket.close()  # fin de la communication
    print(f"Fin de la connexion avec {address}")


# client.py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9999


def client_connect(message): # I use a third file that runs this method

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((HOST, PORT))

    client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    print(client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Port numbers are unsigned 16-bit, so only go as high as 65,535. Your 90,000 was doomed from the outset.

Comment: If you use `127.0.0.1` for the IP address on both server and client, your code will only work if both are running on the same machine, because `127.0.0.1` is a synonym for *"this machine"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
port = sock.getsockname()[1]
```

to bind to some free random port.

However, if you want to find a free port from some range you can use `try-catch`. First you assign some starting value to `port` and when bind is not successful, you try to bind to the next port. For example:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
hostname = '127.0.0.1'
port = 10000
while port < 12000:
    try:
        sock.bind((hostname, port))
        # bind successfull - port is OK
        break
    except socket.error:
        port += 1
```